# Use props vuejs + symfony

Tags: vue.js, symfony4

I am looking to retrieve a variable pass in the url of twig to send it to VueJS to call an API. But when I use PROPS from Vuejs it does not work.

Here is my twig template:

```
{% block body %}
    <Realmstatus v-bind:region="{{ app.request.get('_route_params')['region'] | escape('js') }}"></Realmstatus>
{% endblock %}
```

App.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import Realmstatus from './components/Realmstatus';

/**
 * Create a fresh Vue Application instance
 */
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(Realmstatus)
});
```

Realmstatus.vue

```
    <template>
       <div>
    <p>{{ region }}</p>
           <p> {{ info }}</p>
       </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                info: null
            }
        },
        props: ['region'],
        mounted () {
            axios
                .get('https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/realm/status?locale=fr_FR&apikey=wgxwm68tvdvrs4v77s8rfa6jf52tx4tn')
                .then(response => (this.info = response))
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I can not find where the error would come from. Can you help me please ?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: did you try to log this `{{ app.request.get('_route_params')['region'] | escape('js') }}` check if region arrives well here...

Comment: The region arrives well it is on the side seen that it does not happen

Comment: Do you have any idea where the problem would come from? thank you

Answer (score 0):

An error is thrown because the default delimiters of VueJS are conflicting with the ones you are using in your twig templates.

You can change the delimiters on your Vue instance :

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['${', '}']
})
```

or globally if you want to impact all instances

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}'];
```

You can then use both templating engines side by side :

```
<h1>{{ twig_variable }}</h1>
<p>${ vue_variable }<p>
```

Source : https://blog.elao.com/fr/dev/comment-integrer-vue-js-application-symfony/

Comment: Up to you to use the delimiters that fit your needs the most.